# Find out the sequence number of a pattern

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Consider below table

Table

```
ActivityId      Flag       Type
----------      -----      -----
1               N                              
2               N 
3               Y           EXT
4               Y
5               Y           
6               N
7               Y           INT
8               Y      
9               N
10              N
11              N
12              Y           EXT
13              N             
14              N
15              N
16              Y           EXT
17              Y           
18              Y           INT
19              Y           
20              Y           EXT
21              Y
22              N
23              N
```

First record has always `Flag = N` and then any sequence of `Flag = Y` or `Flag = N` can exist for next records. Every time flag changes from `N` to `Y`, the `Type` field is either `EXT` or `INT`. Next `Y` records (before next `N`) might have `Type = EXT` or `INT` or NULL and this is not important.

I want to calculate `Cycle No` for this sequence of `N/Y`. First cycle starts when `Flag = N` (always first record has `flag = N`) and cycle ends when flag changes to `Y` and `Type = EXT`.  Then, next cycle starts when flag changes to `N` and ends when flag becomes `Y` and `type = EXT`. this is repeated until all records are processed. The result for above table is:

Result

```
ActivityId      Flag       Type      Cycle No
----------      -----      -----     --------
1               N                       1       
2               N                       1
3               Y           EXT         1
4               Y
5               Y           
6               N                       2
7               Y           INT         2
8               Y                       2
9               N                       2
10              N                       2
11              N                       2
12              Y           EXT         2
13              N                       3
14              N                       3 
15              N                       3
16              Y           EXT         3
17              Y           
18              Y           INT
19              Y           
20              Y           EXT
21              Y
22              N                       4
23              N                       4
```

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 (no `LAG`/`LEAD`).
Can you please help me find the SQL query to calculate `Cycle No`?

Comment: what you have tried so far

Comment: try this,
select * from temptable a join temptable b on a.activityid + 1 = b.activityid

Comment: your problem is same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410687/sql-group-by-on-consecutive-records  ...

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal Not exactly, this one has an end of cycle condition.

Comment: If ever there were a case where it made sense to use a cursor, this is probably it.

Comment: @RobertSievers  There is no need for a cursor here.  There is almost never a need for a cursor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a solution, its not pretty, but through stepwise refinement I get to your result:

The solution is in three steps

1. Isolate the activityid for all the possible start cycle and end
   cycle rows.
2. Filter out all the dud start events
3. Number the cycles, and find the interval of activityid for each
   cycle

First i select out all start and end cycle events:

```
with tab as
(select * from (values
(1,'N',''),(2,'N',''),(3,'Y','EXT'),(4,'Y','')
,(5,'Y',''),(6,'N',''),(7,'Y','INT'),(8,'Y','')
,(9,'N',''),(10,'N',''),(11,'N',''),(12,'Y','EXT')
,(13,'N',''),(14,'N',''),(15,'N',''),(16,'Y','EXT')
,(17,'Y',''),(18,'Y','INT'),(19,'Y',''),(20,'Y','EXT')
,(21,'Y',''),(22,'N',''),(23,'N','')) a(ActivityId,Flag,[Type]))

,CTE1 as
( select
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by t1.ActivityId) rn
    ,t1.ActivityId
    ,case when t1.Flag='N' then 'Start' else 'End' end Cycle
from tab t1
where t1.Flag='N' or (t1.Flag='Y' and t1.[Type]='Ext')
)
select * from cte1
```

This returns

```
rn  ActivityId  Cycle
1   1   Start
2   2   Start
3   3   End
4   6   Start
5   9   Start
6   10  Start
7   11  Start
8   12  End
9   13  Start
10  14  Start
11  15  Start
12  16  End
13  20  End
14  22  Start
15  23  Start
```

The problem is now that while we are sure of when the cycle ends, that is when Flag is N and Type is Ext, we are not sure when the cycle starts. Row 1 and 2 both denote a possible start event. But luckily we can see that only a start event following an End event is to be counted. Since we do not have lag or lead we must join the CTE with itself:

```
,CTE2 as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by a1.activityid) rn
       ,a1.ActivityId
       ,a1.Cycle
       ,a2.Cycle PrevCycle
from  CTE1 a1 left join CTE1 a2 on a1.rn=a2.rn+1 
where 

    a2.Cycle is null -- First Cycle
    or
    ( a2.Cycle is not null
    and
    ( 
        (a1.Cycle='End' and a2.Cycle='Start') -- End of cycle
        or 
        (a1.Cycle='Start'  
         and a2.Cycle='End') -- next cycles
    )
    )
    )
select * from cte2
```

This returns

```
rn  ActivityId  Cycle   PrevCycle
1   1   Start   NULL
2   3   End Start
3   6   Start   End
4   12  End Start
5   13  Start   End
6   16  End Start
7   22  Start   End
```

I Select the first start event - since we always start with one, and then keep the END events that follow a start event.
Finally we only keep the rest of the start events if the previous event was an End event.

Now we can find the start and end of each cycle, and number them:

```
,cte3 as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by b1.ActivityId) CycleNumber
    ,b1.ActivityId StartId,b2.ActivityId EndId
from cte2 b1 left join cte2 b2
on b1.rn=b2.rn-1
where b1.Cycle='Start'
)
select * from cte3
```

Which gives us what we need:

```
CycleNumber StartId EndId
1   1   3
2   6   12
3   13  16
4   22  NULL
```

Now we just need to join this back on our table:

```
select
a.ActivityId,a.Flag,a.[Type],CycleNumber
from tab a
left join cte3 b on a.ActivityId between b.StartId and isnull(b.EndId,a.ActivityId)
```

This gives the result you were looking for.

This is just a quick and dirty solution, perhaps with a little TLC you can pretty it up, and reduce the number of steps.

The full solution is here:

```
with tab as
(select * from (values
(1,'N',''),(2,'N',''),(3,'Y','EXT'),(4,'Y','')
,(5,'Y',''),(6,'N',''),(7,'Y','INT'),(8,'Y','')
,(9,'N',''),(10,'N',''),(11,'N',''),(12,'Y','EXT')
,(13,'N',''),(14,'N',''),(15,'N',''),(16,'Y','EXT')
,(17,'Y',''),(18,'Y','INT'),(19,'Y',''),(20,'Y','EXT')
,(21,'Y',''),(22,'N',''),(23,'N','')) a(ActivityId,Flag,[Type]))

,CTE1 as
( select
    ROW_NUMBER() over (order by t1.ActivityId) rn
    ,t1.ActivityId
    ,case when t1.Flag='N' then 'Start' else 'End' end Cycle
from tab t1
where t1.Flag='N' or (t1.Flag='Y' and t1.[Type]='Ext')
)
,CTE2 as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by a1.activityid) rn
       ,a1.ActivityId
       ,a1.Cycle
       ,a2.Cycle PrevCycle
from  CTE1 a1 left join CTE1 a2 on a1.rn=a2.rn+1 
where 

    a2.Cycle is null -- First Cycle
    or
    ( a2.Cycle is not null
    and
    ( 
        a1.Cycle='End' -- End of cycle
        or 
        (a1.Cycle='Start'  
         and a2.Cycle='End') -- next cycles
    )
    )
    )

,cte3 as
(
select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by b1.ActivityId) CycleNumber
    ,b1.ActivityId StartId,b2.ActivityId EndId
from cte2 b1 left join cte2 b2
on b1.rn=b2.rn-1
where b1.Cycle='Start'
)

select
a.ActivityId,a.Flag,a.[Type],CycleNumber
from tab a
left join cte3 b on a.ActivityId between b.StartId and isnull(b.EndId,a.ActivityId)
```

Comment: Thanks but the query eliminates any record between cycle end and next cycle start. It also eliminates any record that their flag=Y and Type is INT. I do not want to exclude any record from the table, looking for the result I showed in question.

Comment: @Bob  I think you have implemented this query incorrectly.  I have just tested it and got the exact output as required in your question.

Comment: You were right. I implemented again and got the exact result I was looking for. Thanks Soren for such a detailed answer to my question.

Answer (score 1):

If you are happy with recursion, this can be achieved rather simply with a bit of comparison logic to the preceding row when ordered by your `ActivityId`:

```
declare @t table(ActivityId int,Flag nvarchar(1),TypeValue nvarchar(3));
insert into @t values(1 ,'N',null),(2 ,'N',null),(3 ,'Y','EXT'),(4 ,'Y',null),(5 ,'Y',null),(6 ,'N',null),(7 ,'Y','INT'),(8 ,'Y',null),(9 ,'N',null),(10,'N',null),(11,'N',null),(12,'Y','EXT'),(13,'N',null),(14,'N',null),(15,'N',null),(16,'Y','EXT'),(17,'Y',null),(18,'Y','INT'),(19,'Y',null),(20,'Y','EXT'),(21,'Y',null),(22,'N',null),(23,'N',null);

with rn as    -- Derived table purely to guarantee incremental row number.  If you can guarantee your ActivityId values are incremental start to finish, this isn't required.
(   select row_number() over (order by ActivityId) as rn
            ,ActivityId
            ,Flag
            ,TypeValue
    from @t
),d as
(   select rn               -- Recursive CTE that compares the current row to the one previous.
            ,ActivityId
            ,Flag
            ,TypeValue
            ,cast(1 as decimal(10,5)) as CycleNo
    from rn
    where rn = 1

    union all

    select rn.rn
            ,rn.ActivityId
            ,rn.Flag
            ,rn.TypeValue
            ,cast(
                case when d.Flag = 'Y' and d.TypeValue = 'EXT' and d.CycleNo >= 1
                        then case when rn.Flag = 'N'
                                    then d.CycleNo + 1
                                    else (d.CycleNo + 1) * 0.0001    -- This part keeps track of the cycle number in fractional values, which can be removed by converting the final result to INT.
                                    end
                        else case when rn.Flag = 'N' and d.CycleNo < 1
                                    then d.CycleNo * 10000
                                    else d.CycleNo
                                    end
                        end
            as decimal(10,5)) as CycleNo
    from rn
        inner join d
            on d.rn = rn.rn - 1
)
select ActivityId
    ,Flag
    ,TypeValue
    ,cast(CycleNo as int) as CycleNo
from d
order by ActivityId;
```

Output:

```
+------------+------+-----------+---------+
| ActivityId | Flag | TypeValue | CycleNo |
+------------+------+-----------+---------+
|          1 | N    | NULL      |       1 |
|          2 | N    | NULL      |       1 |
|          3 | Y    | EXT       |       1 |
|          4 | Y    | NULL      |       0 |
|          5 | Y    | NULL      |       0 |
|          6 | N    | NULL      |       2 |
|          7 | Y    | INT       |       2 |
|          8 | Y    | NULL      |       2 |
|          9 | N    | NULL      |       2 |
|         10 | N    | NULL      |       2 |
|         11 | N    | NULL      |       2 |
|         12 | Y    | EXT       |       2 |
|         13 | N    | NULL      |       3 |
|         14 | N    | NULL      |       3 |
|         15 | N    | NULL      |       3 |
|         16 | Y    | EXT       |       3 |
|         17 | Y    | NULL      |       0 |
|         18 | Y    | INT       |       0 |
|         19 | Y    | NULL      |       0 |
|         20 | Y    | EXT       |       0 |
|         21 | Y    | NULL      |       0 |
|         22 | N    | NULL      |       4 |
|         23 | N    | NULL      |       4 |
+------------+------+-----------+---------+
```

Comment: your query works but please continue to read my comment. every set of activity ids belong to one particular work item. For simplicity I excluded that field (WorkId). Your query is instant for above table but it becomes extremely slow (almost no progress) when I tested with around 100 Work Ids. Real data has around 1 million work id in which each has several activity id.

Comment: @Bob  This is important contextual information that should have been included in your question.  Please update your question to better reflect your actual requirements.