# Grouping in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, grouping, gaps-and-islands

I have data similar to below. I need to group the status column based on the occurrence of data.

```
Id  Status  Value
1     K      1
2     K      3
3     K      2
4     B      2
5     B      3
6     K      6
7     J      5
8     J      2
```

I want data as below

```
Status  Value
K       6
B       5
K       6
J       7
```

I need the cumulative sum of the value column.In the status column if the data is same consecutively, then I need to add the value columns. I cannot apply `group by`. In the example given K is repeated twice, because they are not consecutive.

I have tried below query, but it doesn't work as required.

```
select Status,
       (select sum(value)
        from table t2
        where 
          t2.Status = t.Status and
           t2.SNO <= t.SNO
       ) as total
      
from table t;
```

Comment: what version of SQL Server are you using ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL: Group By on Consecutive Records](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410687/sql-group-by-on-consecutive-records)

Comment: Please post some example data from t and t2

Comment: In short - you have bad design of database. One solution that I see is to add new column with values like 1,1,1,2,2,3,4,4 and group by this column.

Comment: whats SNO number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a Gaps and Islands Question

I tackle these by using the incrementing Id and combing this with ROW_NUMBER window function

```
--Using a CTE just to replicate the sample data
;WITH cteX (Id,Status,Value)
AS(
    SELECT 1,'K', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'K', 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'K', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'B', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,'B', 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,'K', 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,'J', 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,'J', 2
)
SELECT
      Grp = Id - ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY X.Status ORDER BY X.Id) 
    , X.Id
    , X.Status
    , X.Value
FROM 
    cteX X
ORDER BY
    X.Id
```

This gives this result set, note the Grp column

```
Grp     Id      Status  Value
------- ------- ------- -------
0       1       K       1
0       2       K       3
0       3       K       2
3       4       B       2
3       5       B       3
2       6       K       6
6       7       J       5
6       8       J       2
```

Then combine with a CTE or derived table you can get your expected output

```
--Using a CTE just to replicate the sample data
;WITH cteX (Id,Status,Value)
AS(
    SELECT 1,'K', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'K', 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'K', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'B', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,'B', 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,'K', 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,'J', 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,'J', 2
)
SELECT Y.Status
     , Value = SUM(Y.Value)
FROM
(
    SELECT TOP 100 PERCENT
          Grp = Id - ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY X.Status ORDER BY X.Id) 
        , X.Id
        , X.Status
        , X.Value
    FROM 
        cteX X
    ORDER BY
        X.Id
) Y
GROUP BY
    Y.Grp, Y.Status
```

Output

```
Status  Value
------- -------
B       5
J       7
K       6
K       6
```

**Update Question include "Preserve order" solution**

Just include an `Order by MIN(Id)`

```
--Using a CTE just to replicate the sample data
;WITH cteX (Id,Status,Value)
AS(
    SELECT 1,'K', 1 UNION ALL
    SELECT 2,'K', 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 3,'K', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 4,'B', 2 UNION ALL
    SELECT 5,'B', 3 UNION ALL
    SELECT 6,'K', 6 UNION ALL
    SELECT 7,'J', 5 UNION ALL
    SELECT 8,'J', 2
)
    SELECT 
         Y.[Status]
        ,[Value] = SUM(Y.[Value])
    FROM
    (
        SELECT
              Grp = Id - ROW_NUMBER()OVER( PARTITION BY X.[Status] ORDER BY X.Id) 
            , X.Id
            , X.[Status]
            , X.[Value]
        FROM 
            cteX X
    ) Y
    GROUP BY
        Y.Grp, Y.[Status]
    ORDER BY
        MIN(Y.Id) --preserve the Status Order
```

Output

```
Status  Value
------- -------
K       6
B       5
K       6
J       7
```

Comment: I love this!  But can you explain how the grp works?  I'm playing around with it and I don't see how it comes with the group numbers.  The first group of "K" is grp = 0, but I can't see how it comes up with that.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply, but I want to preserve the order of the status.How can I achieve that?

Comment: @jackstraw22 if you split up the "Grp" column into two columns, one for `Id` and the other for the `Row_Number` function then you'll see how it works it out.

Comment: @CrazyCoder - i've updated the answer to include a solution that preserves the order of the status