# GROUP BY Specific Column and sum one columns consecutive values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a dataset by using this query:

```
SELECT ThanaId, RoadId, (ToChain-FromChain) as TotalChain, FromChain, ToChain, SurfaceType
FROM Segment
WHERE ThanaId = (SELECT MIN(ThanaId) AS ThanaId FROM RdLineDiagTemp)
   AND RoadId = (SELECT MIN(RoadId) AS RoadId FROM RdLineDiagTemp)
ORDER BY FromChain
```

The Dataset is:

```
 ThanaId | RoadId | TotalChain | FromChain | ToChain | SurfaceType
 54701   |1368    |3100        |0          |3100     |BC
 54701   |1368    |2000        |3100       |5100     |BC
 54701   |1368    |750         |5100       |5850     |BC
 54701   |1368    |920         |5850       |6770     |BC
 54701   |1368    |73          |6770       |6843     |BC
 54701   |1368    |2000        |6843       |8843     |BC
 54701   |1368    |4007        |8843       |12850    |Ert
 54701   |1368    |2000        |12850      |14850    |BC
```

I want to show it like this:

```
 ThanaId | RoadId | TotalChain | FromChain | ToChain | SurfaceType
 54701   |1368    |8843        |0          |8843     |BC
 54701   |1368    |4007        |8843       |12850    |Ert
 54701   |1368    |2000        |12850      |14850    |BC
```

Here, each consecutive TotalChain is summed for the consecutive same surface type. What query should I write to achieve this?

Comment: HI! there are two BC SurfaceType, why?

Comment: How do you know consecutive surface type, there is no column to know the order.

Comment: I'm thinking he wants a JOIN or SUM or GROUP BY.

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410687/sql-group-by-on-consecutive-records

Comment: The title says GROUP BY... You're on the right track!

Comment: @Mr.J these are consecutive rows of same surfacetype

Comment: @JatinPatel FromChain indecates serial

Comment: @FaisalNabil . . . If the chain can be broken (say the 4th row were simply missing), then the answers below will still combine all initial BC values into a single row.  I don't know if this is desirable, but you should probably access George Betsos's answer.  And, if this is a problem, ask *another* question, clearly explaining what needs to be done.

Answer (score 2):

This is a gaps and islands problem.

You can use a query like the following:

```
SELECT ThanaId, 
   RoadId, 
   SUM(TotalChain) AS TotalChain, 
   MIN(FromChain) AS FromChain, 
   MAX(ToChain) AS ToChain, 
   SurfaceType
FROM 
(
   SELECT ThanaId, RoadId, (ToChain-FromChain) as TotalChain, 
          FromChain, ToChain, SurfaceType,
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ThanaId, RoadId 
                             ORDER BY FromChain) -
          ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ThanaId, RoadId, SurfaceType 
                             ORDER BY FromChain) AS grp
   FROM Segment
   WHERE ThanaId = (SELECT MIN(ThanaId) AS ThanaId FROM RdLineDiagTemp)
         AND 
         RoadId = (SELECT MIN(RoadId) AS RoadId FROM RdLineDiagTemp)
) AS t
GROUP BY ThanaId, RoadId, SurfaceType, grp
ORDER BY FromChain
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/59127/4)

**Note:** I assume that field `FromChain` determines row order.

Answer (score 0):

Use difference of `row_numbers` as `Giorgos Betsos` said this is a *gaps and islands problem.*

```
select ThanaId, RoadId, max(ToChain) - min(FromChain) TotalChain, 
                        min(FromChain) FromChain, max(ToChain) ToChain, SurfaceType 
from (
    select *,
          row_number() over (order by ThanaId, RoadId) Seq1,
          row_number() over (partition by SurfaceType order by ThanaId, RoadId) Seq2 
    from table t
) tt
group by ThanaId, RoadId, SurfaceType, (Seq1-Seq2)
```